# Using Packages with swift to extend SwiftUI Colors

Tags: swift, colors, package, swiftui, package-managers

I've built a very simple and lightweight extension for the `Color` object in SwiftUI that allows me to pass in hex color codes for UI elements. example: (Color(hex: "234323")) and when I just create a file in the project and drop my code in there it works but if I create a package with the same exact code I get the error: **Use of undeclared type 'Color'**

[image: code in the package where the error appears.]

Am I just not understanding the package correctly? or does anyone think they might understand my mistake? thank you

Comment: What is your package name? If its `Color` it could potentially be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13.0, *)

public extension Color {
    init(hex: String) {
        self.init(.blue)
    }
}
```

This built fine for me as a demo in a new Swift package. I wonder if you just need to clean your build folder or restart Xcode?

Comment: oddly enough, I realized today the error only presents itself when I try to run the live preview on one of my development devices. so if I just run it in the swiftUI view its fine. I think this is probably where the error lies.